# pylint: ignore multiple in rcfile

Tags: python, pylint

In my django project I'm using an externally written app which is badly written. Now I want to ignore this app from my pylint reporting, however I can't get pylint to ignore it. Pylint is already ignoring the South migrations, like this:

```
[MASTER]
ignore=migrations
```

However, the documentation states that multiple ignores can be specified. But I've tried a few and couldn't get them to work.

Doesn't work:

```
[MASTER]
ignore=migrations,badapp
```

Also doesn't work:

```
[MASTER]
ignore=migrations
ignore=badapp
```

My project structure is like this:

```
|-- goodapp
|    |-- models.py
|    |-- tests.py
|    +-- views.py
|-- badapp
|    |-- models.py
|    |-- tests.py
|    +-- views.py
|-- manage.py
```

I'd rather not sprinkle my code with `# pylint: skip-file`, but rather configure pylint using the rcfile.

Comment: I think this does not work, because pylint can't find the __init__.py file in "goodapp" and "badapp".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ignore can be set multiple times when given as a command line option, eg

```
pylint --ignore=migrations --ignore=badapp mymodule.py
```

But not in the configuration file (see the [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) documentation). Though

```
[MASTER]
ignore=migrations,badapp
```

should work, if not that should be reported as a bug.

Comment: a quick test locally makes me think that it works as expected

Comment: doesn't work for me on pylint 1.3.1 (CentOS 6, Fedora 21 both have pylint 1.3.1). maybe it's a bug. I created 3 directories `a,b,c` with the same `tmp.py` and tried using a `pylintrc` with `ignore=a,b,c` and I also tried `--ignore=a,b,c`. The config file and the command line option both did not work.

Comment: --ignore=<file>
 Add <file or directory> to the black list. It should be a base name, not a path. You may set this option multiple times. [current: %default]
[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2503717/452708)

Answer (score 2):

You can do `--ignore=migrations,badapp` but not for example `--ignore=lib/migrations,apps/badapp` - pylint does not understand full paths, only basenames. Also in my version it ignores all multipe instances of `--ignore` in the command line using only the last `--ignore` parameter.