# Pylint: Disable specific warnings for specific folder

Tags: python, pylint

We have a Python project laid out like this:

```
project/
├── .pylintrc
├── module1.py
├── module2.py
└── tests/
    ├── test_module1.py
    └── test_module2.py
```

Our unit and function tests reside in the folder called `tests/`. When it comes to tests the pylint warnings `missing-docstring`, `invalid-name` and `protected-access` are not relevant. On the other hand, these warnings are very useful for the actual code in the project.

My question is whether it is possible to add ignores for `missing-docstring`, `invalid-name` and `protected-access` in the `.pylintrc`-file that apply to modules in the `tests/`-folder *only*?

If possible, we do not want to add `#`-disables for these warnings to every test-module inside the folder.

Comment: see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47584560/4201810)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I'm aware you can't disable specific warnings for entire directories or files.

However, you can disable all warnings for specific directories using the following on the command line:

```
--ignore=<file[,file]>
```

The file here can be a directory.

Personally, and I know you said you'd rather not, I'd add a disable to the top of each file.

Comment: As I said, I want to disable specific warnings for specific folders and/or modules, not *all* warnings. It appears that it's not possible to do, however. Apparently, there's an issue on Github for it: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/618

Comment: The pylint issue is quite old. No official solution yet. Maybe use flake8. Also see
https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/issues/3767#issuecomment-1319916278

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can create .pylintrc in the tests folder, and another in the project folder.

Add tests to the "ignore" section of the project

```
[MASTER]
ignore=tests
```

See: https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/run.html

Then run separately:

```
pylint project
pylint project/tests
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is that if you want to enable other pylint checks on your test code, you have to duplicate your configuration.

Comment: Also, I think that many IDEs will not be able to switch between the two different `.pylintrc` files depending on the current file.