# Is it possible to add per-file disable rules to pylint rcfile?

Tags: pylint

I want to disable some pylint errors from a specific Python file using my pylint rcfile. For complicated reasons, I cannot use disabling comments in the Python file itself. I have to set the rules in the pylint rcfile. However, I can't find documentation about whether "disable" can be made to work for only specific files. Please advise.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182847/pylint-disable-specific-warnings-for-specific-folder

Comment: see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47584560/4201810)