# Pylint ignore directory issues

Tags: python, directory, pylint

I'm using pylint to run code analysis on my project. However it needs to ignore one of the directories.

The only solutions I have found (eg [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503717/pylint-ignore-by-directory)) are several years old, and I have not had luck getting their methods do not work.

What I have tried:

- Using the --ignore flag from command line. `eg: pylint --ignore=directory_name`
- Putting an ignore command in the pylintrc file: `ignore=directory_name`
- With and without *'s and /'s on  the directory names

---

I will add that I am running pylint on a *directory of packages* and thus my pylint command looks like:

```
pylint3 --rcfile=pylintrc ./Data/Scripts/*
```

I am expecting that the ignore parameter is given higher priority than the "*" when I list the folders for it to search.

Answer (score 0):

I fell a little bad replying to my question so soon after posting it, but I found a solution. I don't particularly like it though.

The issue was that the card use a wildcard to specify directories, and the pylint ignore does *not* look at the names that are specified explicitly in the command.

So the solution was to create a `__init__.py` file in the /Data/Scripts folder (so that pylint treats it like a package), and then tell pylint to analyze the /Data/Scripts folder.

The folder structure now looks like:

```
Scripts
 + package_1
     file.py
 + package_to_ignore
     file.py
     file.py
 + package_3
     file.py
 __init__.py
```

`__init__.py` did not have to contain anything