# pylint: Exclude directory

Tags: python, pylint

Suppose I have the following directory structure:

```
adir/
  __init__.py
  afile.py
bdir/
  __init__.py
  bfile.py
  adir/
    __init__.py
    afile.py
```

I want to run pylint on everything, **except** the directory `bdir/adir`.

Is there any way to do this?  Things that do not work:

- `--ignore=bdir/adir`
- `--ignore_patterns=.*bdir/adir.*`
- Any of the answers in [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503717/pylint-ignore-by-directory)
- `--ignore=adir` (this will ignore both of the `adir`'s - not what I want).

It seems that pylint's ignore-filters only work with the name of the **file or directory**, not the full path.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Here is the line that you can add in your .pylintrc file: 

```--ignore=<file[,file]>
```

https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/run.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182847/pylint-disable-specific-warnings-for-specific-folder?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be `--ignore-paths=bdir/adir`. Works both on Windows and Linux.

Regarding `--ignore_patterns=.*bdir/adir.*`:

- it contains typo: `--ignore_patterns` -> `--ignore-patterns`
- according to [documentation](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html):

> ignore-patterns
>
> Files or directories matching the regex patterns are skipped. The regex matches *against base names*, not paths. The default value ignores emacs file locks
>
> Default: ^.#

You specify not a base name (it includes parent folder).